# How to write a derived query in Netezza SQL?

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to query the data for inviteid based. For each inviteid I need to have the top 5 IDs and ID Descriptions.

I see that the query I wrote is taking all the time in the world to fetch. I didn't notice an error or anything wrong with it.

The code is:

```
SELECT count(distinct ID),
  IDdesc,
  inviteid,
  A
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    IDdesc,
    inviteid,
    RANK() OVER(order by  invtypeid asc ) A
  FROM Fact_s
    --WHERE dateid ='26012013'
  GROUP BY invteid,IDdesc,ID
  ORDER BY invteid,IDdesc,ID
) B
WHERE A <=5
GROUP BY A, IDDESC, inviteid
ORDER BY A
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ORDER BY invteid,IDdesc,ID` from the subquery? (I suspect that it won't affect the speed of the query much, but it does appear to be unnecessary.) Also, can you give us some idea of numbers of records on the table, number of records returned by the query, current execution time and desired execution time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood you requirement completely, but as far as I can tell the `group by` in the derived table is not necessary (just as the `order by` as Mark mentioned) because you are using a window function.

And you probably want `row_number()` instead of `rank()` in there.

Including the result of `rank()` in the outer query seems dubious as well.

So this leads to the following statement:

```
SELECT count(distinct ID),
       IDdesc,
       inviteid
FROM (
  SELECT ID,
         IDdesc,
         inviteid,
         row_number() OVER (order by invtypeid asc ) as rn
  FROM Fact_s
) B
WHERE rn <= 5
GROUP BY IDDESC, inviteid;
```